# Ajax responses in console but not showing anything in html tag for select onchange

Tags: php, ajax

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#program').change(function(){
        var short = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "ajaxx.php?getsubjects",
            dataType : "html",
            data : {short:short},
            success : function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                var data = JSON.parse(response);
                $('#clas').html(data.subjects);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<select  name="class" id="clas" class="form-control sel" required="required"></select>
```

```
<?php
include"connection.php";

if (isset($_GET['getsubjects'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['short'])) {
        $v = $_POST['short'];

        if($_POST['short'] != '') {
            $output = "";
            $v =  $_POST['short'];      

            $sqll = "SELECT class FROM `classes` WHERE program = '$v' ";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sqll);

            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $n = $row1['class'];
                $output .= "<option value='$n'> $n </option>";
            }

            $arr['subjects'] = "<option value=''> Select a grade </option>" . $output;
            echo json_encode($arr);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

this is my code for all html,ajax and php i'am having data response in console but not in my html select tag, please help me out i've tried a lot codes but its working in xampp server not on google.

Comment: Are you sure the JSON you are receiving is correctly formatted. Is JSON.parse() throwing any error on console? Can you post what you are getting on the console?

Comment: <!--
-->{"subjects":"<option value=''> Select a grade <\/option><option value='Grade 1'> Grade 1 <\/option><option value='Grade 2'> Grade 2 <\/option><option value='Grade 3'> Grade 3 <\/option><option value='Grade 4'> Grade 4 <\/option><option value='Grade 5'> Grade 5 <\/option><option value='Grade 6'> Grade 6 <\/option><option value='Grade 7'> Grade 7 <\/option>"}

Comment: VM2077:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (add-std.php:2962)
    at u (VM2038 jquery.js:3)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM2038 jquery.js:3)
    at k (VM2038 jquery.js:3)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM2038 jquery.js:3)

Comment: There is the problem. The JSON you are getting is not properly formatted, so parsing it throws an error. Could you please add a screenshot of your console to the question for a better look at the output?

Comment: https://hiveschool.org/hive/Screenshot%20(12).png

Comment: Could you try removing the dataType : "html" thing and try again?

Comment: i've tried this too but nothing happened

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208349/discussion-between-prakhar-londhe-and-muhammad-shoaib).

Comment: can you show the console log after it?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to convert html to json in your php file 
Just echo every option in loop i.e

```
echo "<option value=''> Select a grade </option>";
while($row1= mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $n = $row1['class'];
    echo "<option value='$n'> $n </option>";
}
```

And in javascript success function just set response to your html

```
$('#clas').html(response) ;
```

Comment: i don't know what's happening but its still not working